# How to get dartdoc to include additional documentation?

Tags: dart, documentation, dart-pub, dartdoc

I would like to understand if there is a way for me to include additional documentation with the API docs that get generated by `dartdoc`.

According to the [Package layout conventions](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/package-layout) there is a `getting_started.md` file included inside the `doc/` directory and is displayed like this ...

```
enchilada/
  ...
  doc/
    api/ ***
    getting_started.md
```

How does that file get incorporated into the docs by `dartdoc` and where does it show up in the output?  I've tried to simply add my own `*.md` files in the `doc/` directory but they don't appear to get used.

I have also read about **Categories** in the dartdoc [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc) which states:

> **categories**: More details for each category/topic. For topics you'd like to document, specify the markdown file with markdown: to use for the category page. Optionally, rename the category from the source code into a display name with 'name:'. If there is no matching category defined in dartdoc_options.yaml, those declared categories in the source code will be invisible.

So I then tried to reference the additional documents in the `dartdoc_options.yaml` file like this ...

```
dartdoc:
  categories: 
    "Getting Started":
      markdown: doc/getting_started.md

    "Search Filters":
      markdown: doc/search_filters.md


  categoryOrder: ["Getting Started", "Search Filters"]
```

But that too did not generate any results.

Does anyone know how if it's possible to include additional documentation and if so how to accomplish this?

Comment: did you find some clues here ? I'm in the same case as you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I disagree - arbitary .md is well catered for and I use an md file as the top level explainer for each of the libs I need to document.

There are 'gotchas' though and as others have pointed out:

1. your method/function docstring should include an @category statement for the topic categories you intend
2. your options.yaml should include the category, and their order
3. you need *both* the category in the docstring AND the matching reference in the .yaml or one or the other will be ignored
4. you need a matching .md file (I place mine in a docs folder)

Then you will have something like this in your yaml:

```yaml
dartdoc:
  categories:
    "Getting Started":
      markdown: docs/install.md
      name: install
    "Authorization":
      markdown: docs/auth.md
      name: authorization
    
  categoryOrder: ["Getting Started", "Authorization"]
```

and your method/function will have this docstring:

```dart
/// {@category Authorization}
```

don't forget to create the .md file too.

Answer (score 1):

Dartdoc does not allow arbitrary .md files to be included in API documentation.  You can create links to them in the README.md or other documentation, e.g. via GitHub or another web address serving them.

For example, the dartdoc package does this for the 'contributing' documentation, and it shows up in the API docs, here: https://pub.dev/documentation/dartdoc/3.0.0/index.html

Categories will only render if at least one element in the source code is declared as a member of that category, so that feature isn't well suited to this use case.

Comment: The Flutter project is using that approach in its API documentation. See https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/9331 .