# Include additional documentation in dartdoc like go_router does

Tags: flutter, dartdoc

The package, go_router, successfully lists additional documentation as topics on its [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/) page.
You see them as a sidebar on the left-hand side of the page.

I've examined the approach used and read the [documentation](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc#advanced-features) provided:

go_router's [dartdoc_options.yaml](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/dartdoc_options.yaml) file.
[image]

And yet the topics don't appear on my [documentation](https://pub.dev/documentation/fluttery_framework/latest/) page.

What am I missing??

Running `dart doc .` locally produces the expected directory, `doc/api`. However, the file, `categories.json`, has an empty list, `[]`. This means to me DartDoc is not even recognizing the categories I've defined.

I did note in the documentation:
'If there is no matching category defined in dartdoc_options.yaml, those declared categories in the source code will be invisible.'

And yet go_router doesn't implement such tagging and it still works??

What am I missing??

Thanks.

Similar StackOverflow questions:

[How to get dartdoc to include additional documentation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413614/how-to-get-dartdoc-to-include-additional-documentation)

[Using dartdoc categories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70703324/using-dartdoc-categories)

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I figured out what I was missing.

In your source code (under the lib directory), you have to insert in the class comments the '@category' directive:

```
/// {@category Get started}
/// {@category Configuration}
/// {@category Transition animations}
/// {@category Named routes}
/// {@category Redirection}
```

That's what the authors of [go_router](https://github.com/flutter/packages/blob/main/packages/go_router/lib/src/route.dart#L134) did.

I got the hint from another stackoverflow post on the subject:

'[at least one element in the source code is declared as a member of that category,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56413614/how-to-get-dartdoc-to-include-additional-documentation/69168498#69168498)'

Yesh so, there you are.